# Create column taking number of values from one column and actual value from another column

Tags: google-sheets

I have two columns, A and B, where A contains the number of values for corresponding value in B. I want to create column C that contains the number of values from A but with the value from B. So for example:

```
| A |  | B  |
| 2 |  | 40 |
| 3 |  | 60 |
```

Should produce:

```
| C  |
| 40 |
| 40 |
| 60 |
| 60 |
| 60 |
```

So 2 of 40 and 3 of 60. This could be in memory (I only want to use C in a formula, don't really need it as an actual column) or as its own column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a try on below formula-

```
=ArrayFormula(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN("@",TRUE,REPT(B1:B2&"@",A1:A2)),"@")))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, seems to work though I get an error saying that the text result for TEXTJOIN is longer than the maximum of 50000 characters. A and B are a lot bigger in my sheet than in the example.

Comment: Yes `TEXTJOIN()` has a character limitation of `50000`.

Comment: Marking this as correct as your answer led me to find:
=ArrayFormula(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(REPT(D:D&"@";F:F); ;9^99);"@"))) which ignores the maximum of 50000 characters. Thanks! :)